# build library ZXing for android project

Tags: android, zxing

hi i want to make QR code scanner to my android app using ZXing library
i already success try it with "Scanning via Intent" method before
now i try different approach

my problem is i always get this error

[image]

my step
1. download zxing master from [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing#sthash.ZAdNKBgH.dpuf)
2. download jar from repository [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/#sthash.ZAdNKBgH.dpuf)
3. import ‘android’ folder from zxing-master in eclipse
4. create libs folder and copy core.jar in there
5. right click in CaptureActivity - properties - java build path - library tab - add core.jar path

i don't know why i still get error after add jar path...
i already try clean project, swith workspace, using latest jar file but still same
any idea?

---

**@update  @Nickolai Astashonok**

eclipse error
    '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

i try to change java compiler using 1.7 (default 1.6) by
right click project - properties - java compiler tab
but it's seem my target API not fullfil requirment (my API 15)
how to use ZXing in java compiler 1.6?

---

**Update @Sean Owen**

when i changed using java compiler level 1.7 and clean project it's says

```
Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 15
```

i wanna target my aplication runs for ICS (API 15)
i'm not sure if in '*captureActivity androidManifest using minSDK 19*' and '*myProject androidManifest using minSDK 15* will be running well

so i guess i better stick with java compiler 1.6

meanwhile i found this [link](http://techiedreams.com/android-zxing-barcode-scanner-integration/)
based on that link i need to use zxing library version 4.5.1 (java compiler 1.6)
because version above using java compiler 1.7

[image]

but i can't find any download link to 'zxing library version 4.5.1'

Comment: What errors eclipse shows you?

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok i already update my question with error...please check

Comment: do right click on project and goto Android Tools->Fix Project properties and add library mentioned there. After that right click project again goto BuildPath->Configure Build path-> order and export and check all checkboxes. Now Clean Build the project. This should solve your problem

Comment: @NightCrawler i stil get same error "operator is not allowed for source level 17 below" (before more than 100 error now just 86)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but I think the answer is this: the source code indeed requires Java 7. You simply need to set your IDE project to use Java 7. The supplied Maven build already works correctly in this regard. It is not true that API 15 or any other Android API needs Java 6.

Comment: sory if my question not clear...i already update my question
hope this time more clear

Comment: There is no version 4.5.1. Android 4.4 is not required to compile with Java 7. In fact, Barcode Scanner itself targets API 15. This is an issue with your build.

Answer (score 0):

I found 4.5.1 but I don't know how to download it! if you figured it out let me know too please. 
https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/?r=2927#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fandroid

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I solve this by doing:

1. change the java compiler to 1.7 (like what Nickolai Astashonok suggested)
2. change the target version to 19 (Android 4.4)
3. Clean the project again, you will see lots of errors removed but there is still some errors related to missing of CameraConfigurationUtils.java
   Please go to below link to download and copy the file into your project as per the path suggested.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.java

4. Clean the project again, you should be able to clear all the errors and use the sample application in the 'android' folder.