# Zxing Library project import error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, zxing

as [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818566/build-library-zxing-for-android-project) question does not get any acceptable or correct answer so i raised that question again.... please i am trying to import Zxing library project in my workspace- but i am getting problem that it gets stuck or conflicted with jre1.6 and jre 1.7..
in library project code- `FORMATS_FOR_MODE = new HashMap<>();` those line gives error that- `'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7` and if i change the project compliance and jre to 1.7 then it will give error-
`Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.`

please tell me if any one solved this problem, i am stucked very badly thanks in advance... and this is not the duplicate question as it related to library import...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818566/build-library-zxing-for-android-project

Comment: @dylan meeus but there is no any acceptable answer there...

Comment: But did you try the upvoted answer / other answers that worked for some people?

Answer (score 1):

You could manually "downgrade" the code to Java 6.0 if you don't want to follow the answers in the other questions.

- Replace `<>` with `<ProperType>` (<- not the String "ProperType", but the proper type of your generic class)
- Replace `switch` on Strings with `if(foo.equals(bar)){}else if(foo.equals(bar2)...``

If I remember correctly that are the only relevant "syntax changes" you need to do.